# Using Youtube as video storage for my mobile app

Tags: youtube-api, file-storage

I'd like to create an mobile app which allows end users to share videos between themselves. I am in doubt with YouTube API right now because my plan has been to create YT channel and allow users to upload videos on it and then stream their videos from the channel.

Is it allowed to that in this way? If not would you recommend me any file storage which is fast, cheap and easy to use please? I also checked Dropbox but the streaming is so slow.

Answer (score 1):

You can upload video's using YouTube's upload API ([Python sample code here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python#upload_a_video), you can also call via other languages and HTTP: [API explorer here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/)).

The upload call will return a [video resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos) which includes [an id](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#id).  You can then use this ID to create URLs for your users to share, or use it to embed the video in [your website](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference), [Android](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) or [iOS](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper) app.

Comment: Matt, thanks for reply however I know how to do it technically. I am little bit afraid of getting ban from Youtube. When anyone uploads inappropriate content on my channel I will get ban and app won't work. Is there any chance how to avoid this situation? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not a lawyer and can't comment on legal matters.  All I can do is point you to the Terms of Service for YouTube and YouTube's API:
https://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms and 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/api-services-terms-of-service

Answer (score -2):

You can send a `POST` request that identifies the target of the complaint. The user who is making the complaint and the text of the compliant itself. The request can also specify the reason for the complaint by using a [`<category>`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#youtube_data_api_tag_category) tag that has a **scheme** attribute value of **http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/complaint-reasons.cat**. The tags **term** attribute value must be one of the following terms:

- CHILDABUSE - The video contains acts of child abuse.
- DANGEROUS - The video contains harmful or dangerous acts.
- HATE - The video contains hateful or abusive content.
- PORN - The video contains sexual content.
- RIGHTS - The video infringes on the complainant's rights or copyright.
- SPAM
- VIOLENCE - The video contains violent or repulsive content.

The following XML demonstrates how to add a complaint about a video.

```
POST /feeds/api/videos/VIDEO_ID/complaints HTTP/1.1
Host: gdata.youtube.com
Content-Type: application/atom+xml
Content-Length: CONTENT_LENGTH
Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN
GData-Version: 2
X-GData-Key: key=DEVELOPER_KEY
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">
  <summary>
Please ignore this complaint. I'm testing a YouTube API and 
needed to issue a complaint to test the add complaint function.
Per the value of the category tag, pretend I am complaining
about a video that contains violent or repulsive acts.
```

Comment: I think the OP was asking if YT can be used to store video, not how to register complaints via the YT API. I am not sure, therefore, this is an answer to the question.